# Can a Java method have more than 255 local variables?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, low-level, opcode

The `iload` Java opcode is used to push a value from the local variable array (LVA) onto the operand stack.

This opcode takes a single byte as a parameter ([en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings)), which serves as an index  for the LVA.

If one element of the LVA is always the reference to the object (I guess this isn't the case for static methods, but lets ignore those for now), and if exactly one byte is used as an index (256 possible values), then how can a method have access to more than 255 different local variables?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for Java methods to have more than 255 local variables.  The `wide` opcode instruction can be used to modify an `iload` or `aload` instruction to use a 16-bit index instead of an 8-bit index, meaning that you can have up to 65536 different local variables in a function, as long as the `wide` opcode ends up getting used.

That said, note that Java local variables do not necessarily correspond one-to-one with JVM local variables.  It's possible that the Java compiler could look at your code, notice that space for locals can be reused in some contexts, then map multiple Java locals to the same JVM local variables.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think (OpenJDK) javac does that. I suspect it doesn't use `wide` either. I don't have Java installed on this machine to test it (and I can't be bothered to look at the code).

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline- I'm not sure whether any specific implementation of `javac` does this, though in principle it is possible to do so (since the JVM supports it).  If you know of any references about this, I'd love to see them.

Comment: It seems that at least one compiler actually does this - see the other answer.

Comment: 65536 variables inside of a single function is a limit unable to be reached because the maximum size of a function is 65535 bytes.

Answer (score 12):

I tried it for you by writing a program with 300 local vars. This snippet:

```
System.out.println(a255);
System.out.println(a256);
```

compiles into this:

```
3575: getstatic     #16                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
3578: iload         255
3580: invokevirtual #53                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
3583: getstatic     #16                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
3586: iload_w       #256                // Utf8 a196
3590: invokevirtual #53                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
```

Note: compiled with Eclipse and javac, with exact same results.

Comment: I mean something like `C4 15 01 00`. `iload_w #256` is an instruction, not an opcode.

Comment: I'm afraid `javap` doesn't do that. If you know a way, I'll do it.

Comment: I take it you don't want to open the `class` file in a hex editor?

Comment: And just dump all bytes to you? How's that going to help you?

Comment: Of course, then there's http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings , but I wanted an independent source to verify.

Comment: There's this repetitive sequence: `c4 15 01 00 b6 00 35 b2 00 10` `c4 15 01 01 b6 00 35 b2 00 10`... and the fourth byte keeps increasing.

Comment: Decoding from wikipedia: `c4 15 xx xx` => `wide iload xxxx`; `b6 00 35` => `invokevirtual #0x35`; `b2 00 10` => `getstatic #0x10`

Comment: Wikipedia didn't let us down :)

Comment: It seems to be something weird with the javap application when using iload_w... javap is showing the two-byte index as a reference to the constant pool whereas it should really just be "iload_w 256" right? It also references what can be found at #256 in the constant pool which is the identifier for local var a196... doesn't make sense..

Comment: @fast-reflexes - Looks like sometimes the compiler reuses slots (the first 255) without harming the overall flow. Maybe in the sample code you wrote it shuffled out some variable from the first 255 slots temporarily